# If $X\to X/G$ is a universal covering map of CW-complexes, then is $G$ always free on the cells of $X$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, cw-complexes

Let $X\to X/G$ be a universal covering map of CW-complexes, then does $G$ always act freely on the cells of $X$? I know if the action of $G$ is free, then $X\to X/G$ is a normal covering map, I wonder if the converse is always true for CW-complexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The converse is not true, i.e. $G$ need not act freely on $X$. Take the sphere $S^2$ with two cells, $e_0^i,e_1^i$ of each dimension $0\leq i \leq 2$ and define the action of $\mathbb Z$ on the CW-complex of $S^2$ by: $$n(e^i_j)=(-1)^ne^i_{k}\,\,\,;k=j+n\,\text{mod} \,2$$ The action clearly is not free and the map $S^2 \rightarrow S^2/\mathbb Z$ is the universal covering $S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb {RP}^2$.

Comment: Sorry, but if $X\to X/G$ is a universal cover then $G\cong \pi_1(X/G)$, here $\pi_1(Rp^2)=\mathbb{Z}_2$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @6666 the Theorem you are mentioning has as a supposition $G$ is free action, or sometimes an equivalent statement for existence of neighborhood satisfying nonempty intersections by group action implies equal group elements

Comment: This example is basically the same as "Let $X$ be a point and let $G$ be an arbitrary group acting trivially on $X$.  Then $X\to X/G$ is a universal covering map."  What if $G$ acts faithfully? (We can reduce to this by replacing $G$ with $G/\operatorname{ker}(G\to\operatorname{Aut}(X))$.)

Comment: @KyleMiller what if $G=\pi_1(X/G)$?